# Rinse cycle problems on GE GLD4458R00CS dishwasher

Tags: repair, appliances

I'm stumped with this problem and I'd love some help

I have a GE GLD4458R00CS dishwasher. It's about 7 years old. after noticing that our dishes haven't been coming out very clean, I have attempted to repair it, but after 2 days I can't locate the source of the problem. Here's what I know:

Basically I think the sprayer arms are just not spraying water at all. Not like a weak flow or something, just absolutely no water at all.

It is not dirty or clogged. I have disassembled, cleaned and re-installed practically every filter and hose on the entire machine, including the lower and middle sprayer arms, the fine mesh filter, the sump trap cover and sump filter, the drain hose, and the drain valve. Oh also the soap dispenser door definitely works as well.

It's not the door switch (I don't think) because it seems to operate normally. The tub will fill when the door is closed, and stop filling when you open the door mid cycle, then resume when you close the door again.

I don't think it is related to the float switch. I cleaned that part and did a few test runs and it seems to be operational. eg, the tub won't fill without it, but when it is in place the tub seems to fill appropriately.

My understanding of the wash cycle (normal, not heated dry) is that it should 1) rinse 2) drain 3) wash with soap, (the longest part of the cycle 4) drain 5) rinse again. What happens is that the tub fills, the machine is quiet for a period of time, and then it drains. this leads me to conclude that the water inlet valve is OK, and the main pump is OK. The whole cycle seems to take about the correct amount of time, which makes me think it's not the control board. but I just don't know what's left?!

My basic thoughts are that it could be:

the water inlet valve. I know I said I thought it was good, but perhaps it is faulty and underfilling the tub?

the main pump/motor. Are there multiple motors/pumps on this model? is there a reason it would pump in and drain but not rinse?

the control board. Some faulty circuit is not letting it correctly advance to the appropriate cycle

the float switch. because....?

I'm drowning in dishes here. Can someone let me know what dumb thing I haven't thought of and which (expensive) part I need to order to fix it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you refilled the salt and rinse fluid? Or have you changed brand on rinse fluid and washing powder / tablets? Have you run it through a cleaing cycle? Some specify the hottest cycle or a special setting with a cleaner...

Comment: @solar mike, yeah I've run a cleaning tab through to get rid of scale build up. The inside is pretty clean so I don't think that's the issue. Also during a cycle where it should be rinsing/spraying, I hear *nothing*. So its not just a "no soap" issue. the water is not pumping. I took the front kickplate off during a test cycle and you can see the motor is not operating.

Comment: I had mine go funny, not washing etc etc... So I disconnected the electrical supply for 2 days, then re-connected it - it came up and worked fine... So you could give that a go. I reckon mine had got confused and needed a reset.